# Microsoft Kinect (For Windows)

Tags: windows, kinect

Okay so I am not sure if a lot of you have started to work on Microsoft Kinect for Windows that has been released in February 2012. I am trying to start developing and I wanted to know if there are any tutorials I can find on how to use the SDK or if someone can guide me How the RGB stream can be captured using the Kinect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many tutorials. Some can be found at [Channel 9's Kinect Quick Start Series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart) , [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=kinect) also has many articles on Kinect. All of the classes and variables found in the SDK can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855419.aspx), on [Rob Relyea's Blog](http://robrelyea.wordpress.com/category/kinect/) there are many tutorials. And if you ever are struggling, you can visit the [Kinect Development Chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13111/kinect-developement) (assuming you have 20 rep).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't start with Channel 9, or any tutorials for that matter. The most enjoyable way to jump into the Kinect and start messing around with stuff is to install the [Developer Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx). It was update 3 days ago to include some really cool 3D point cloud stuff. Download/install the toolkit, run the Kinect Studio application it comes with, and spend some time checking out what the Kinect is capable of. If you see something of interest, install it to your computer and open it in Visual Studio. If you don't have Visual Studio, you can download the [C# Express version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express) for free. The source code is all very well commented and I find that's the best way to learn by example. You don't have to sit through Channel 9's sometimes painful videos or spend time reading a blog, you can just jump in and have fun with it. If you get stuck, then refer back to Channel9 or come back to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Although this is a good idea, he should go to channel 9 first to see the bery basics and then this would be a great idea +1

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start learning is MSDN, and where you got the driver for kinect. They offer many tutorials and videos that explain most concepts for the kinect.

Comment: Could you tell me exactly where to look? I can't seem to find appropriate help. Keeping in mind, I'm a total newbie at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Kinect 1.0](http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/practical-windows-kinect-in-c.html) for kinect for Windows SDk  1.0